# iOS B2B App Rejection

Tags: ios, b2b

Recently my iOS app got rejected and response from Apple was:

> 1.0 Binary Rejected
>
> Before You Submit We found that your app is not appropriate for the App Store since it is designed specifically for B2B for sale in.

I didn't understand what it means. How can I re-submit the app to App Store.

Comment: The message appears incomplete. Are you sure are pasting all of the original message?

Comment: Also, do you have an enterprise account? It is possible that the problem is you're attempting to publish to the app store from an enterprise account.

Comment: In iTunes, it showing like that only.

Answer (score 0):

You might be given B2B application like below. It is indented to add pricing to your application.
[image]

Change this option and upload again. It will work

Comment: Thanks for your response. And it is in disable mode.